# Is there a way to activate the default opam switch on shell startup?

Tags: shell, ocaml, zsh, opam

It's very tedious to have to activate the default switch every time I want to start using ocaml with `eval $(opam env --switch=default --set-switch)`. I was given an option when I first initialized `opam` to update my `.zshrc` with a line to do this on startup but I must have missed it because the initialization continued on without my input. I tried manually adding the line to my `.zshrc` but the switch that's activated is *not* my default switch, which uses `ocaml v5.0.0`. Instead, it activates another switch I created with `v4.14.0`.

For context, the line I added to my runtime config was

```
[[ ! -r /Users/USERNAME/.opam/opam-init/init.zsh ]] || source /Users/USERNAME/.opam/opam-init/init.zsh  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Maybe the answer to my question is that it's not recommended to activate a switch by default?

Comment: You are throwing away the stderr, so if there is anything wrong with your code, you won't notice it.  Also, for debugging run this piece of code with `set -x` enabled, and investigate the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally recommended to activate a switch by default if you always want to use a specific version of a tool or language. In your case, it seems that the line you added to your `.zshrc` is not activating the default switch, but rather a different switch you created with version 4.14.0 of OCaml.

To activate the default switch every time you start a new terminal session, you can add the following line to your `.zshrc` file:

```
eval $(opam env --switch=default --set-switch)
```

This will activate the default switch and set the environment variables for that switch. Make sure to remove any other lines that activate a different switch.

After adding this line to your `.zshrc` file, run the following command to source your updated `.zshrc` file:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

This should activate the default switch every time you start a new terminal session.

Comment: Sourcing `~/.zshrc` may not necessarily be idempotent, so it would be better to just run `eval $(...)` this one last time, or start a new shell to let it be initialized using the updated `.zshrc`.

Comment: That definitely did it, thanks! I thought that since the line above looked so different from the `eval` one, there would be a better thing to add to `.zshrc`. But this definitely makes sense!